# Finding the value of improper integral given some other integral's value

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Calculate the value of I. $$I=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^p}dx$$. Where 
$0<p<1,\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{p-1}}{1+x}dx=\frac{\pi}{\sin(p\pi)}$. 
$$\text{Attempt}$$ No concrete progress at all to be honest. Just tried doing $I(s)=\int e^{-sx^p}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^p}dx$ and then calculating $\frac{dI(s)}{ds}$ . But didn't help much . Another idea was calculating definite integral of $\frac{e^{ix}}{x^p}$ and then extracting the value of imaginary part of this integral.

Comment: One could apply Ramanujan's Master Theorem. The evaluation of the related integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x^p}dx$ using this technique can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3012090/how-to-evaluate-this-nonelementary-integral/3012122#3012122).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Laplace transform, we get
$$I=\int_0^\infty\mathscr{L}_t(\sin x)\mathscr{L}^{-1}_t(x^{-p})dt\\
=\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{p-1}}{1+t^2}\frac1{\Gamma(p)}dt$$
We can easily find $$\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{p-1}}{1+t^2}dt$$ by using substitution $u=t^2$:$$\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{p-1}}{1+t^2}dt=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{u^{p/2-1}}{1+u}du=\frac{\pi}2\csc\frac{p\pi}2$$
Therefore, $$I=\frac{\pi}2\csc\frac{p\pi}2\frac1{\Gamma(p)}= \Gamma (1-p)\cos\frac{p\pi}{2}$$
When $0<p<2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

> As mentioned within the comments this integral can be tackled utilizing [Ramanuajan's Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem) as it was similarly done in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3012090/how-to-evaluate-this-nonelementary-integral/3012122#3012122).

To actually apply Ramanujan's Master Theorem we have to reshape the integral a little bit. To be precise enforcing the substitution $x^2=u$ yields to the following

$$\begin{align}
\mathfrak{J}=\int_0^{\infty}\sin(x)x^{-p}~dx&=\int_0^{\infty}x^{-p}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}dx\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\infty}x^{-p}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-x^2)^n}{(2n+1)!}2xdx\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\infty}u^{-p/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-u)^n}{(2n+1)!}du\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\infty}u^{-p/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+1)/\Gamma(2n+2)}{n!}(-u)^ndu
\end{align}$$

The last integral can be evaluated by applying Ramanujan's Master Theorem with $s=1-\frac p2$ and $\phi(n)=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(2n+2)}$. From hereon we further get

$$\begin{align}
\mathfrak{J}=\frac12\int_0^{\infty}u^{-p/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+1)/\Gamma(2n+2)}{n!}(-u)^ndu&=\frac12\Gamma\left(1-\frac p2\right)\frac{\Gamma\left(-\left((1-\frac p2\right)+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(-2\left(1-\frac p2\right)+2\right)}\\
&=\frac1{2\Gamma(p)}\Gamma\left(\frac p2\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac p2\right)\\
&=\frac1{2\Gamma(p)}\frac{\pi}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi p}{2}\right)}
\end{align}$$

Overall we can write down the equality

> $$\mathfrak{J}=\int_0^{\infty}\sin(x)x^{-p}~dx=\frac1{2\Gamma(p)}\frac{\pi}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi p}{2}\right)}$$

The propesed representation of the integral invoking $\cos\left(\frac{\pi p}2\right)$ can be deduced farily easy by using Euler's Reflection Formula with $z=p$

$$\color{red}{\frac1{2\Gamma(p)}\frac{\pi}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi p}{2}\right)}}=\frac{\pi}{\Gamma(p)}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi p}2\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi p}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi p}2\right)}=\frac{\pi}{\Gamma(p)\sin(\pi p)}\cos\left(\frac{\pi p}2\right)=\color{red}{\Gamma(1-p)\cos\left(\frac{\pi p}2\right)}$$

Answer (score 2):

by taking laplace transform of

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(x)}{x^p}}dx=\frac{1}{\Gamma{(p)}}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{s^{p-1}}{s^2+1}ds=\Gamma{(1-p)}\cos{\frac{p\pi}{2}}          
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

NOT A SOLUTION:

As part of my work on another [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3049949/methods-to-solve-int-0-infty-frac-cos-leftkxn-rightxn-a-dx)  I have been faced with the same problem. I have scoured and have only found a [HyperGeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) representation for the integral. It is convergent for $p > 1$, $p \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: If it's not a solution, then it would be better to post it as a comment

Comment: Well it is a solution per sae, just not something that requires deviation. If fits the exact HyperGeometric function I linked. 

Do you think it requires some of the basic algebra required so the skilled mathematicians on the page will be able to follow>?

Comment: I do apologise for any semantic, spelling or basic grammar errors - my glasses are cracked :(