# Find the function $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n-1}(-x)^n}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals, hypergeometric-function, polygamma

I want to find the function defines by :
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n-1}(-x)^n}{n!}$$

Where $H_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$ is the Harmonic series.

### My work

We have the relation with the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) :

$$\psi(x+n)-\psi(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{x+k}$$

So setting $x=1$ we have :

$$\psi(n)-\psi(1)=H_{n-1}$$

So we have :

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\psi(n)-\psi(1))(-x)^n}{n!}$$

With the help of [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28Digamma%28n%29-Digamma%281%29%29%2Fn%21*%28-x%29%5En%20at%20n%3D1%20to%20infinity) I get :

$$f(x)=-x\operatorname{F}_1^{(1,0,0)}(1,2-x)$$

Where $F_1(a;b;z)$ denotes [the confluent hypergeometric function of the first kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheFirstKind.html)

Now applying the [Ramanujan master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem) we get :

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}f(x)dx=\Gamma(s)(\psi(-s)-\psi(1))$$

### My question :

Can someone add some steps to get the result of Wolfram alpha ?

Any helps is greatly appreciated

Thanks a lot for all your contributions .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{{da}}{}_1F_1 (a;2; - x) = \frac{d}{{da}}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{(a)_n }}{{(2)_n }}\frac{{( - x)^n }}{{n!}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{(a)_n (\psi (n + a) - \psi (a))}}{{(2)_n }}\frac{{( - x)^n }}{{n!}}} \\ = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{(a)_n (\psi (n + a) - \psi (a))}}{{(n + 1)!}}\frac{{( - x)^n }}{{n!}}} .
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
 - x\left[ {\frac{d}{{da}}{}_1F_1 (a;2; - x)} \right]_{a = 1} & =  - x\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{(1)_n (\psi (n + 1) - \psi (1))}}{{(n + 1)!}}\frac{{( - x)^n }}{{n!}}}  \\ & = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {(\psi (n + 1) - \psi (1))\frac{{( - x)^{n + 1} }}{{(n + 1)!}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {(\psi (n) - \psi (1))\frac{{( - x)^n }}{{n!}}} .
\end{align*}

Comment: That's ok for me .Thanks !