# Is the converse of Ramanujan's Master Theorem also true?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, mellin-transform

[Ramunajan's Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem) states that if a complex-valued function $f(x)$ has an expansion of the form

$$\displaystyle f(x)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {\,\varphi (k)\,}{k!}}(-x)^{k}$$

then the [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) of $f(x)$ is given by

$$\displaystyle \int _{0}^{\infty }x^{s-1}\,f(x)\,\operatorname {d} x=\Gamma (s)\,\varphi (-s)$$

Here $\varphi(s)$ is some function (say analytic or integrable).

Now, what about the converse of this? Say that we know that the Mellin transform of $f(x)$ is equal to $\Gamma (s)\,\varphi (-s)$, is it then true that $f(x)$ has an infinite expansion in the form given above?

I couldn't find anything about this question on Wikipedia or somewhere else.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3099031/applications-of-ramanujans-master-theorem/4026016#4026016

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a partial converse to the Master Theorem, note that if $\mathcal M[f(x)]=\Gamma(s)\varphi(-s)$ then $$f(x)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}x^{-s}\Gamma(s)\varphi(-s)\,ds.$$ The poles of $\Gamma$ are simple and are the non-positive integers, so the residue at an integer $-t\le0$ is $$\lim_{s\to-t}(s+t)\Gamma(s)=\lim_{s\to-t}\frac{\Gamma(s+t+1)}{\prod\limits_{i=0}^{t+1}(s+i)}=\frac{(-1)^t}{t!}.$$ Thus if $\varphi$ has no singularities and does not have roots at the non-positive integers then the residue theorem gives $$f(x)=\sum_{t\ge0}\operatorname{Res}(x^{-s}\Gamma(s)\varphi(-s),-t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\varphi(k)(-x)^k}{k!}$$ which is the original statement.

In Berndt's *Ramanujan's Quarterly Reports*<sup>1</sup>, it is noted that

> In the final section of the first report, Ramanujan derives certain
> expansions for four functions by **assuming** that a type of converse theorem to
> the Master Theorem holds. More specifically, he determines a power series
> for the integrand from the value of the integral. In fact, Ramanujan's converse
> to the Master Theorem follows from the inversion formula for Mellin
> transforms. Although Ramanujan proceeded formally, all of the results that
> he obtains are, indeed, correct.
>
> <sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

The four functions considered are

1. $\left(2/(1+\sqrt{1+4x})\right)^n=p_*^{-n}$ where $p_*$ is the positive root of $p^2-p-x$, giving $\varphi(q)=n\Gamma(n+2q)/\Gamma(n+q+1)$;
2. $\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)^{-n}=e^{-n\operatorname{arcsinh}x}$, giving $\varphi(q)=n2^{q-1}\Gamma((n+q)/2)/\Gamma((n-q)/2+1)$;
3. $\int_0^\infty a^{q-1}x^n\,da$ where $a\ge0$, $n>0$ and $x$ solves $\log x=ax$, giving $\varphi(q)=n(n+q)^{q-1}$;
4. $\int_0^\infty a^{r-1}x^n\,da$ where $x$ solves $aqx^p+x^q=1$ with $a>0$, $0<q<p$ and $0<pr<n$, giving $\varphi(r)=nq^{r-1}\Gamma((n+pr)/q)/\Gamma((n+pr)/q-r+1)$.

Evidently in all these cases $\varphi$ is not analytic in the whole left-plane, but I suspect the cancelling of gamma terms with $\Gamma(-s)$ may be why the identity still holds.

---

<sub>Reference</sub>

<sub>[1] Berndt, B. C. (1984). Ramanujan's Quarterly Reports. *Bulletin of the London Mathematical Society*. 16(5):449-489.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: +1 My guess is that Ramanujan understood some equivalent form of Mellin transform in a very different and simpler fashion. Maybe his understanding was not perfect but he understood how to avoid most pitfalls in his approach.